# Cannot increment integer inside the foreach loop

Tags: c#, arrays, list, methods, argumentnullexception

I have a C# method to convert from a list into an array. The code goes like this:

```
public String[] ConvertToArray(List<InstallationControl> list)
        {
            String[] Array = null;
            Int32 i = 0;
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                Array[i] = item.Value.ToString();
                i++;
            }

            return Array;
        }
```

However, it's always giving me the Null exception. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: You're not initializing your array. String[] Array = new String[list.Count]

Comment: I think you should just use the `ToArray()` method... That or rewrite your loop to something that makes more sense, like a traditional for instead of a foreach with an index variable... Doesn't that just defeat the purpose of using foreach? Plus initialize your array to `list.Count()`.

Answer (score 4):

You are not initializing the array you are trying to fill.

```
String[] Array = new String[list.Count]
```

Should solve your problem.

This will create an array of [list.Count] strings. You should be aware that each of those strings are null until you them assign a value.

[MSDN Arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the array

```
String[] Array = new String[list.Count];
```

or simply

```
String[] Array =list.Select(x=>x.Value.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Comment: I guess you meant `list.Select(r=> r.Value.ToString()).ToArray()`

Answer (score 0):

Change the line to initialize the array

```
String[] Array = new String[list.Count];
```

Should work